# "Closing changes: [on hold], unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized"

Tags: discussion

It seems there are relevant changes coming soon to how posts are closed: [Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons) (MetaStackOverFlow).

Questions:

- How these changes could change our own set of custom 'off topic' reasons for the EL&U  stack?
- Will we have nostalgia from the lack of the TL reason?
- Are these changes capable to generate an increase in the number of closed questions?

Comment: The function of TL will be replaced by site specific reasons on 'off-topic' How that list is made I'd like to know though. I think the 'Unc;ear what you're asking' reason would result in -lots more- 'on holds'

Comment: Is the objective to increase the number of closed questions? I thought it was to reduce them?

Comment: @Mari-Lou, it is difficult to talk about closed questions in abstract sense, however their reduction, occurred after the cerberus' invective, did not do so well at EL&U, which has been flooded with trivial questions even if ELL is now opened and in use.

Comment: I once suggested that new members had to check a box explaining they had read and understood the rules. It's not a bullet-proof deterrent, but at least they would know the existence of the FAQs and read the guidelines (or maybe not...) for making and answering a question. Sometimes, however, the seemingly trivial questions can provide wonderful insights on how a language functions. Trivial isn't always bad.

Answer (score 3):

So, we'll still have ***Duplicate*** and ***Off Topic***, but pretty soon our four other closevote reasons...

> *Not Constructive
>
>   Not A Real Question
>
>   Too Localised
>
>   General Reference*

...will be replaced by *three* new alternatives...

> ***Unclear What You're Asking
>
>   Too Broad
>
>   Primarily Opinion-based***

I think ELU might have a bit of a problem there. I've just realised our current FAQ doesn't actually define *GR* - but I thought it used to, and don't recall any debate here on meta about removing it.

ELU gets a lot of really basic questions from non-native speakers, many of which are closed as *GR*. Presumably we'll need to change the FAQ to justify saying they're *OT* instead now. I'm assuming we can't just say they should go to ELL without saying why they can't stay *here*, and I'm not sure it's possible on SO to closevote as *Belongs on XXX* while *XXX* is still in Beta.

---

Anyway, it looks like TPTB don't endorse whatever we thought *General Reference* stood for, so we either have to bite the bullet and allow questions like [the meaning “off”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115124/)  (sic), or we need to decide whether the site really is for *linguists, etymologists, and (**serious**) English language enthusiasts*.

Personally, I think we should include under *Off Topic* a sub-category called something like ***Common knowledge among Anglophones*** (effectively, the old *General Reference*).

I don't really have an opinion on the demise of *Too Localised* - most times when I've closevoted for that reason, I've been overruled (or not supported) anyway.

Comment: We can define some custom Off Topic reasons, and create GR again. On that Meta page, it says "[The Off Topic list] is also the place to address any closing reason that applies to one site but not others (for instance, the "General Reference" close reason on English Language and Usage is moving here)." I'm trying to find more information on that.

Comment: @simchona: Well, am I right in thinking *somebody* removed the previous reference to ***GR*** in our FAQ? I thought it said something along the lines of *"can be satisfied by a single link to a standard online resource"*, but I don't really recall. And it still seems to me that *as a general principle* TPTB don't really want ***GR*** to be used as a reason for closevoting on SO, even if ELU can make a special case for our requirement.

Comment: What I suspect is that when the changed the "about" page, there was a trickle down into the FAQ. The other SE sites don't have GR, that's true, but it's an accepted way of life for ELU. I'll look into editing the FAQ.

Comment: [If there are per-site sub-reasons for off-topic, then plain off-topic will no longer be avaialble](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185088/the-default-off-topic-close-reason-cannot-be-selected-from-the-new-close-dialo/185101#185101) (only the predefined sub-reasons or the free-form comment). This wasn't clear in the original announcement.

Comment: One of the pre-defined sub-reasons can be "Off topic", surely?

Comment: If you're looking for the new GR, it's under off topic now.

Comment: If you want to migrate general reference questions to ELL, you've totally misunderstood either "general reference" or the purpose of ELL.

Comment: @Martha: Again with the lectures. You have your preconceptions about what GR means, and the purpose of ELL. If they're not the same as mine it's not because I "misunderstand" your "truth". It's because ***we disagree***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: but I'm *always* right! Didn't you get the memo?

Comment: @Martha: Dang! I *keep* forgetting that! :)

Comment: ...seriously, although I expect we do actually disagree on the scope of GR (for both ELL and ELU), surely even you would accept that some questions that get asked on ELU are simply too basic, and ought to be on ELL.

Comment: Oh, I do dearly wish for a "migrate to ELL" button, but it's not so much because the questions are basic, but more because it's clear they're asking *because they're learning English*.

Comment: @Martha: I expect we'll get one when ELL comes out of beta. But for now I think we still need to firm up on exactly where we should be drawing the line (a tricky issue, which was one reason ELL took so long to get off the ground).